# How to convert Columns into datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statsmodels, arima

**Please refer the image in the link to take a look at my dataset.** https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LJQP.png

I am trying to convert these columns into datetime index and country name from first column into column names. I have tried using transpose, pivot but nothing is working. I actually want to apply ARIMA model to it and as it does not support axis=1 argument, so I have only one options is to change column names into datetime index. Please help, if you have any solution to solve this problem.

Comment: Avoid at all times to using images in your post, use a plaintext sample of your data-frame, makes it easier for members to assist.

Comment: I will remember that from next time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country/Region': ['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria'],
                   '1/22/20': [1, 0, 0],
                   '1/23/20': [0, 2, 3],
                   '1/24/20': [0, 1, 2]})
df = df.T
country = df1.iloc[0].to_list()
df.columns = country
df = df.drop('Country/Region')
print(df)
```

The Output:

```
        Afghanistan Albania Algeria
1/22/20           1       0       0
1/23/20           0       2       3
1/24/20           0       1       2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to convert the columnn names to datetime. The following should work:

```
df.columns= pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a combination of melt and pivot to get the columns as needed.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Albania', 'Bahamas', 'Bhutan'],
                   '1/22/20': [0, 0, 0],
                   '1/23/20': [0, 0, 0],
                   '1/24/20': [0, 0, 0]})

df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['country'], var_name="date", value_name="value")
df_melt['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_melt['date'])

df_pivot = pd.pivot(df_melt, index='date', columns='country')
df_pivot.columns = df_pivot.columns.droplevel()
print(df_pivot)
```

Output:

```
country     Albania  Bahamas  Bhutan
date                                
2020-01-22        0        0       0
2020-01-23        0        0       0
2020-01-24        0        0       0
```